# Error running Unix command from Perl

Tags: perl, unix, sh, perl-module, mod-perl

I am trying to redirect the output and error to a file in Unix through a Perl script.

The command is running fine in Unix, but while running the Perl script it is throwing the error `sh: & is unexpected`. I tried using escape character also

Command:

```perl
`ls -lrt $myfile >>& $output`
```

Also used Command:

```perl
`ls -lrt $myfile >> $output 2>&1` - got ambiguous output redirect error
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There's a very good chance that what you're trying to do is best done natively in perl anyway.

Comment: I am trying to redirect the output & error of a unix command into a file inside a perl script

Answer (score 1):

Backticks use `/bin/sh`. You're trying to redirect STDOUT and STDERR? The syntax is:

```
>$output 2>&1
```

You also need to convert your file names to shell literals. They might contain spaces, for example, or worse.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote('ls', '-lrt', $myfile);
$cmd .= '>'.shell_quote($output).' 2>&1';
`$cmd`
```

Comment: this is not working I tried. It is throwing "ambiguous output redirect".

Comment: When using backticks?

Comment: it's /bin/csh. I can not change this environment as I have limited access to unix env.

Comment: No, `/bin/sh` is not `/bin/csh`.

Comment: this is shell type. I got it using echo $SHELL in unix

Comment: Who cares about that. It has nothing to do with the question of the answer. Again I ask, did you get that error when using backticks?

Comment: I tried >$output 2>&1. it's giving me error. now I am trying to check the 2nd answer. the problem is I am now trying in bash shell while in office I have c shell

Comment: Why you are talking about `bash` and `csh`??? The question is about backticks in Perl, and it uses `/bin/sh`. I really don't care what results in you got in `csh` or `bash`. Stop saying the solution gives an error when you haven't even tried it yet.

Comment: I am not getting you. in unix (in my office) I ran ls -lrt xx >> test.txt 2>&1, it was giving me "ambiguous output redirect", when I searched internet for solution, it gave me to use cmd >>& output file. so the command in unix ls -lrt xx >>& test.txt is working fine. though if I use them in perl it's not working.

Comment: Why are you saying all that??? It's got nothing to do with the question and the answer. I know `>>& test.txt` doesn't work from backticks, seeing as I explained why and how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry to make you confused. even i am also confused. thanks for the solution(>$output 2>&1, though 2nd one not possible for me as I dont have those modules) but I want to append the output of all the command in this file. this will remove previous out put and will add the last commands output

Comment: but I have one question, why "ls -lrt dd >>t.txt 2>&1" was giving error  "ambiguous output redirect" while I was trying in my office system ?

Comment: and yes using backticks

Comment: Cause you had `csh` or `tcsh` execute a `sh` command. That message specifically comes from `csh` and/or `tcsh`.

Comment: thanks. so is there any way to run the same command in csh or tcsh
or force it execute those command using sh/ksh shell ?

Comment: To execute a `sh` and have it execute an argument pass `-c` and the command as arguments to `sh`. That's what Perl's backticks does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and make sure myfile and output have values

```
$myfile='src';
$output='myoutput';
`ls -lrt $myfile >> $output 2>&1`;
```